# Testing Device for Touch Screen

Tags: java-me

How can i test my j2me Midlet(jad)for touch screen devices?Is there any tool (like WTK provide devices) to test touch screen command List?My application jad is not displaying commands some for Touch screen devices.

Answer (score 1):

Now lot of touch emulators available for testing like Sprint, LG, Sony Ericssion and etc. Nokia also Provide RDA device for testing purpose.

See this link for testing emulators,

- [Sprint](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/mobile_platforms/java_me/javame.jsp)
- [LG](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.tnd.RetrieveDocAndTools.dev?objectType=T)
- [Samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/sch/totalSearch.do?platform1=true&platform2=true&platform3=true&platform4=true&sType=total&topquery=emulator)
- [Sony Ericsion](http://sony-ericsson-j2me-sdk.software.informer.com/)
- [Motorola](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/javame/)
- [Nokia RDA device](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/)

You have to add MIDlet-Touch-Support: true this property on jad file.

Comment: Hey Thanx.                                                         Does any of them work on Linux environment?I have added this attribute in jad but that didnt work.